# leading characters missing in scanned barcode

Tags: bluetooth, barcode, code128

I have paired the barcode reader with a data entry device through bluetooth SPP mode. While reading code 128 barcodes, some of the leading characters are missing. For example, if I scan a barcode for 'FXRGYKD', I could only see 'GYKD' in the device. The barcode readers that I have tried with are 'Socket Mobile CHS 7DI' and 'Symbol CS3070'.

Thanks in advance!

Barcode Image:

[image]

Comment: Any chance you could supply a picture of the barcode you are trying to scan?

Comment: Thanks for your response Brian. Please find the barcode attached

Comment: When I scan the attached barcode, only character 'N' was displayed. When I configure the scanner with any prefix, 'KN' was displayed

Comment: I am able to scan all four characters with my Symbol DS 6707. So it is either the device driver, the data entry device (not usb?) or software that is eating the first three characters. I would try scanning other code 128 barcodes into a plain text editor (Notepad or TextEdit).

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks for your suggestion. The barcodes are scanned properly and all four characters are fed in when paired with the computer. However, I need to pair this with another handheld data entry device via bluetooth whose reseller and manufacturer are not very helpful. I am unsure whether the data entry device expects some sort of prefix appended with the scanned barcode.

Comment: So, when you pair your scanner and computer through this data entry device and scan a barcode into Notepad or TextEdit, the first three characters are 'eaten' by the data entry device?

Comment: Yes. The device that I am calling here as data entry device is a metal analyser. The metal analyser pairs with the barcode reader via Bluetooth. User scans different types of metals and also scans the metal's barcode. The metal analyser has a screen on it where the user can input the decoded barcodes in various text boxes to associate it with the scanned metal. This is where the characters gets eaten. Then this data is uploaded in bulk from the data entry device to the PC. I am sorry if the term 'data entry device' is not appropriate and confusing.

Comment: This might be caused due to the width of your printed image. Maybe some portion of your barcode is getting cropped from the left side. Try extending the width of your label or picture while printing.